# Sewage pump issue

Tags: plumbing, pump, sewer

Today I was in my basement and it smelled like sewage really bad. When I flushed the basement toilet it had a lot of air push back up into it and into the shower drain too. Like it gurgled a lot. I went to the sewage ejector pit and could hear the pump making a motor sound but it wasn't pumping the sewage. I unplugged it and plugged it back in. It immediately started pumping the sewage and it is now acting fine.

What could have caused this?

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe someone in your family flushed an object that jammed the pump.

I would instruct everyone in the family not to flush *anything* other than toilet paper and human waste down the toilet in the basement. Especially if you are on a private septic tank system.

Those pumps are pretty tough but can be clogged if you try hard enough.

Continue to monitor the situation for the next few days to see if the pump fails again. If so it needs repair or replacement.

Good luck!